# mysql left join count always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql

here's my data structure:

```
categories 
id   name
-------------------
1    category1
2    category2
3    category3


items
id    name    cat
-------------------
1     item1   1
2     item2   1
3     item3   1
4     item4   2
```

desired output:

```
cat   category    total_items
-----------------------------------
1     category1   3
2     category2   1
3     category3   0
```

i tried the following query:

```
select categories.id as cat, 
    categories.name as category, 
    count(*) AS total_items from categories 
    left join items on categories.id = items.cat
```

and it will always return 1 for category 3 .. any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select categories.id as cat, categories.name as category, 
       count(items.cat) AS total_items 
from categories 
left join items on categories.id = items.cat
```

The problem with your query is that `COUNT(*)` counts on a row basis, including rows with `NULL`-valued fields from `items` table.

Using `count(items.cat)` instead, leaves `NULL`-valued fields out.

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
select categories.id as cat, 
    categories.name as category, 
    count(*) AS total_items from items
    left join categories on items.cat=categories.id
```